# Why is the destructor of another object called?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My project creates a system tray icon that has a context menu. In this menu, I can click on and create as many notes (like those sticky notes from windows) as I want. However, when I closed my last note (by clicking on the window close button) the destruktor `~Traymenu()` is called. Why? The object `trayMenu` still has an active member, the systray icon...
And what is also interesting, is that the destructor `Note::~Note()` is never called when I close a note window.

main.cpp:

```
#include "note.h"
#include "traymenu.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);    
    Traymenu trayMenu;    
    return a.exec();
}
```

traymenu.h:

```
#ifndef TRAYMENU_H
#define TRAYMENU_H

#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMenu>

class Note;

class Traymenu : public QSystemTrayIcon
{
public:
    Traymenu();
    ~Traymenu();
    void createMainContextMenu();
    void newNote();
    void exitProgram();

private:
    QSystemTrayIcon mainIcon;
    QMenu mainContextMenu;
    std::vector<Note *> noteList;
};
#endif // TRAYMENU_H
```

traymenu.cpp:

```
#include "traymenu.h"
#include "note.h"
#include <QDebug>

Traymenu::Traymenu(){
    mainIcon.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("C:\\program.png")));
    mainIcon.setVisible(true);
    mainIcon.show();
    createMainContextMenu();
}
Traymenu::~Traymenu(){
    qDebug() << "in ~Traymenu()" << endl;
}
void Traymenu::newNote(){
    Note *nN; //new pointer to object of class Note
    nN = new Note(); //Initialize pointer
    noteList.push_back(nN); //add newly created object to a list
}
void Traymenu::exitProgram(){
    //delete this; //deletes traymenu object (icon disappears)
}
void Traymenu::createMainContextMenu(){
    QAction *actionNewNote = mainContextMenu.addAction("Neue Notiz");
    mainContextMenu.addSeparator();
    QAction *actionExitProgram = mainContextMenu.addAction("Programm beenden");
    actionNewNote->setIcon(QIcon("C:\\new.ico"));
    actionNewNote->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
    QObject::connect(actionNewNote,&QAction::triggered,this,&Traymenu::newNote);
    QObject::connect(actionExitProgram,&QAction::triggered,this,&Traymenu::exitProgram);
    mainIcon.setContextMenu(&mainContextMenu);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a reference cicle problem to me

Comment: You aren't deleting the notes stored in the vector. For every `new` there should be a `delete`.

Comment: You are right, this is not implemented yet. This must be the reason why the note's destruktor is not called, ok... But then why is my QSystemTrayIcon destroyed after I close the last note? I don't see where it could come from. Oh but it is not only the QSystemTrayIcon, the whole application itself gets terminated.

Comment: When you close your `QApplication` (`a`), the `a.exec();` function returns, and the application is complete.

Comment: But how is the program closed by closing all note-windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Qt main event loop exits when last window is closed, as per default value of [`QApplication` property `quitOnLastWindowClosed`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop)

So, after creating the application instance, set that to false, something like:

```
QApplication a;
a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Comment: Wohoo, I already knew of this setting but did not thing about it, thanks!! Still I am wondering, why the application first needs to create a window to be quitted after closing that window, since at the beginning there are no windows.

Comment: @user2366975 That makes no sense... :). Application can close due to its last window closing, if there are windows which can be closed. Or, if you mean, how does application quit if it has no windows? By returning from `main` as in any program... Which in most cases requires invoking `quit()` slot of the application main event loop, so the `a.exec();` call returns. And, to be specific, closing last window does not exit application, it just makes `a.exec();` return, and program could do whatever after that, it does not have to exit.